# Grails Gorm: Using maps for collections of objects

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many relationship that I would like to map in Gorm with the backing collection being a map of Strings-to-Objects (rather than the default set).  The grails doc [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps), gives this example:

```
class Book {
    Map authors

    static hasMany = [authors: Author]
}

def a = new Author(name:"Stephen King")

def book = new Book()
book.authors = [stephen:a]
book.save()
```

This is pretty close to what I want, but not quiet.  What this does is stores the arbitrary string "stephen" in a join table separate from the other Book data, along with some other mapping information for this relationship.  When Gorm reloads this object from the database, it simply reads this stored value and uses it as the key in the map.

What I want is something more like @MapKey in Hibernate, where you can specify a property on the value object to be used as the map key.  That way there is no additional table, the values of the map are persisted to the database on a save (keys are pretty much ignored on a save since they are redundant information), and when the collection is loaded from the database, that property is read from the object and used as the map key.

It seems like this is cleaner when your map key is based on data stored in the object because you don't have to go through the work of keeping the map key column up to date with the value object.  In this case, if the author's first name changed from "stephen" to "steve", you would have to update the object, and re-store it under a different key.

Is this possible in Gorm?

Comment: hmmm not sure, but you can create a src/java class with the @MapKey annotation. GORM methods will still be available. Checkout more here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html

Comment: I would have to write the domain class in Java, though, right?

Comment: According to the guide yes, but you can try in src/groovy first, I don't remember if it works.